# Excel chart legend does not list all values

Tags: excel, charts, legend

I'm using Excel for Microsoft 365 Version 2402 (latest [as of March 2024](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-microsoft365-apps-by-date)), and I have the following table and associated chart:

[image: table and chart]

The blue triangle in the center of the chart is for the value `80`. In the legend under the chart, the yellow color is for the range `60-80`, which by the looks of it is actually the interval [60, 80).

How can I make the legend list the value 80 itself?